# Exporting a Blank Excel Sheet

Tags: python, excel, spyder, stock, polygon.io

I am trying to extract the following using Polygon.io.

I have a xcel sheet with Date (column 1) and Ticker (Column 2). I want the trading volume of the ticker for each day for the previous 30 days from the Date listed in Column 1 for the Ticker in column 2. For example, " 2018-07-09" is listed in column 1, "MBVX" is listed in column 2. I want the previous 30 days trading volume for MBVX from 2018-07-09. The output volume will be labeled day 1 volume, day 2 volumes and etc. This the code I am using but when I run the code and it exports the excel sheet there is nothing on it except for my two columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from datetime import timedelta

# Read the Excel sheet into a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\patri\Downloads\Volume data.xlsx')

# Create a new DataFrame to store the volume data
volume_data_df = pd.DataFrame()

# Iterate over each row in the DataFrame
for index, row in df.iterrows():
date = row[0]
ticker = row[1]

# Define the start and end dates for the desired 30-day range
end_date = pd.to_datetime(date)
start_date = end_date - timedelta(days=30)

# Construct the API URL to retrieve historical stock data
api_url = f"https://api.polygon.io/v2/aggs/ticker/{ticker}/range/1/day/{start_date}/{end_date}?apiKey=My API KEY"

try:
    # Send a GET request to the Polygon API
    response = requests.get(api_url)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Extract the volume data from the API response
        data = response.json()
        if data['status'] == 'OK':
            results = data['results']
            for i, result in enumerate(results):
                volume_data_df.loc[index, f"Day {i+1} Volume"] = result['v']
        else:
            print(f"Error retrieving data for {ticker}: {data['error']}")
    else:
        print(f"Error retrieving data for {ticker}.")
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(f"Error making API request for {ticker}: {str(e)}")

# Combine the original DataFrame with the volume data
combined_df = pd.concat([df, volume_data_df], axis=1)

# Export the combined DataFrame to an Excel file
combined_df.to_excel('Volume Data2.xlsx', index=False)
```

It seems like no matter what I change, I get the same results. I have ran the code multiple times with slight variations and I get the same result every time. I am basically the definition of insanity right now.

My ideal excel sheet has my current columns Data, Ticker followed by 30 columns which each the volume for the previous day.

Comment: can you confirm if you are able to get any data whatsoever from `polygon.io` (ie. is the api key working) ?

Comment: The api key is correct. I can use it on other codes, I have written.

Answer (score 0):

You missed converting data only string from `pd.to_datetime(date)`

This code will work.

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from datetime import timedelta

MY_API_KEY = 'Your API Key'

combined_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'Symbol','Offset', 'Volume'])

# Read the Excel sheet into a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel(r'./Volume data.xlsx', usecols='A, B')
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # get Stock Symbol
    ticker = row['Symbol']

    # Get Date and convert date only
    end_date = pd.to_datetime(row['Date'])
    start_date = end_date - timedelta(days = 30)
    start_date_format = "{:04d}-{:02d}-{:02d}".format(start_date.year, start_date.month, start_date.day)
    end_date_format = "{:04d}-{:02d}-{:02d}".format(end_date.year, end_date.month, end_date.day)

    # Construct the API URL to retrieve historical stock data
    api_url = f"https://api.polygon.io/v2/aggs/ticker/{ticker}/range/1/day/{start_date_format}/{end_date_format}?apiKey={MY_API_KEY}"

    try:
        # Send a GET request to the Polygon API
        response = requests.get(api_url)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            # Extract the volume data from the API response
            data = response.json()
            index = 1
            for day_data in data['results']:
                # date only
                trade_date = start_date + timedelta(days=index)
                trade_date_format = "{:04d}-{:02d}-{:02d}".format(trade_date.year, trade_date.month, trade_date.day)

                #Add row data
                offset_format = "Day {:02d} Volume".format(index)
                df2 = {'Date': trade_date_format, 'Symbol': ticker,'Offset': offset_format, 'Volume': day_data['v']}
                combined_df = pd.concat([combined_df, pd.DataFrame.from_records([df2])])
                index = index + 1
        else:
            print(f"Error retrieving data for {ticker}.")
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error making API request for {ticker}: {str(e)}")

combined_df.to_excel('Volume Data2.xlsx', index = False)
```

##### Input Excel File

[image]

##### Output Excel File

[image]

Comment: I am getting the following error The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\patri\.spyder-py3\untitled9.py:20
    ticker = row['Symbol']

Comment: File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:981 in __getitem__
    return self._get_value(key)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:1089 in _get_value
    loc = self.index.get_loc(label)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3804 in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err

KeyError: 'Symbol'

Comment: Can you try uninstall and install dependencies?
`pip uninstall pandas requests datetime` and `pip install pandas requests datetime`

Comment: I am run it on Windows 11. This is my versions
' pip show pandas requests datetime'   => pandas = 2.0.3 , requests = 2.31.0, DateTime = 5.1

Comment: I am currently trying to use spyder. What do you use. I am very new to coding and still struggling to make this work